# How to fix meta tag validation error thrown by W3C validator?

Tags: html

W3C validator throws me the following errors. What are the best process to fix this through html markup? I found some solutions using httaccess.. Wonder if it can be fixed through markup?

Line 5, column 62: **Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta.**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Line 7, column 44: **Bad value encoding for attribute http-equiv on element meta.**

```
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

Line 8, column 67: **Bad value expires for attribute http-equiv on element meta.**

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="mon, 27 sep 2015 14:30:00 GMT">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are validating an HTML5 page, you will have seen this warning at the top of the page:

> **Using experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker.**
>
> The validator checked your document with an experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker. This feature has been made available for your convenience, but be aware that it may be unreliable, or not perfectly up to date with the latest development of some cutting-edge technologies.

There are two issues that are causing your page not to validate: firstly, as the warning says, the html5 validator is only experimental and does not yet cover all features of HTML5, and secondly, the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) itself is currently under development, and new versions are being proposed on a fairly frequent basis. Until the specification is confirmed, and the w3c validator implements checks for the meta tag attributes that you're using, you will continue to get errors.

[Validator.nu](http://validator.nu/) is more up to date with recent candidate HTML5 specs if you want to check HTML5 documents.